# Add icons to Dash Menu from programs

Tags: unity-dash

How do I add program icons into DASH Menu in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

I have downloaded the newest LibreOffice software and need some help with icons.

Does the Ubuntu software store add titles frequently: I didn't see a
newer title I could get from the software makers site?
Thanks, Donald

Comment: similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1282203/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-to-the-show-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-17

Answer (score 11):

To add an icon to the dash you can make custom icons and put them into `~/.local/share/applications`.

Simply copy and paste this template into gedit (or another text editor) and save it as `libreoffice.desktop` into the folder.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Libre Offce
Comment=Office Application
Exec=libre-office
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/libreoffice.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Keywords=libre;office;writer;
Categories=Office
```

If you want it so the icon is available for all users, put the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`.

The Categories=Office bit means it will show up under "Office" in the dash. If the icon is in `/usr/share/pixmaps/libreoffice.png` then actually you can just write `Icon=libreoffice`, there's no need for the full path, but only if it's in that path. Don't know if that works in Gnome 3 though.

If you have translations for the language you can specify them using something like the following:
Name[en_GB]=Libre Office
And replace [en_GB] with the code for each language.

Answer (score 5):

Install the **Main Menu** program, its package name is `alacarte`:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Open it from the Dash by typing **Main Menu**. It shows all the programs which are installed in the Dash. You can do these operations from here:

- Add or remove an application to launch from the Dash
- Change the command used to launch the application
- Specify if it should be launched from terminal
- Change the icon (click on the icon image of the application to do this)